# limiting a search (python)

Tags: python, string, search, asp.net-web-api

```
from shodan import WebAPI

SHODAN_API_KEY = "MY API KEY"
api = WebAPI(SHODAN_API_KEY)

results = api.exploitdb.search('PHP')

print 'Results found: %s' % results['total']
for exploit in results['matches']:
        print '%s:' % (exploit['description'])
```

How can I limit the search to only print the first 5 results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for exploit in results['matches'][:5]:
        print '%s:' % (exploit['description'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your time and learn the Python basics about lists and "slicing" in particular:

http://diveintopython.ep.io/native-datatypes.html